# Can you replace stout with Wychwood King Goblin in Christmas pudding?

Tags: beer, steamed-pudding

So we’d ordered a stout for a Christmas pudding recipe, as part of an online supermarket order. But they’ve substituted it for “King Goblin” from Wychwood Brewery.

Now I’m not a beer drinker, and don’t know much about the flavour it introduces to a pudding. The ruby ale seems lighter in colour, and seems to have a similar alcohol content.

Will this make an appropriate substitution, or should we go and get some stout?

Thanks

Comment: Posting the full recipe for your pudding might help you get more detailed and helpful answers.

Comment: It would also help to know *which* Ruby Ale.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t have the recipe to hand, but it’s a traditional Christmas pudding recipe from Delia Smith. The ale is “King Goblin” from Wychwood Brewery.

Comment: If it's the [recipe I can find](https://www.deliaonline.com/recipes/international/european/british/a-traditional-christmas-pudding), it only calls for 75ml of stout, so it's not a massive contribution to the flavour.  There's also 75ml of barley wine.  I think I've made that recipe in the past.  If so I didn't use barley wine,  but can't recall if I used all stout, or all a malty dark ale.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### This is likely a fine substitution.

I haven't tried King Goblin myself, but looking around online, I see some good signs:

The [description of the beer on drizly](https://drizly.com/beer/ale/wychwood-king-goblin/p13013) (presumably provided by the manufacturer) mentions chocolate malt, and goes on to describe it as:

> an indulgently rich, full, smooth beer

The [reviews on beeradvocate](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/160/62103/) consistently mention flavor notes such as:

- Chocolate
- "Dark fruit" or raisins
- Caramel
- Nutty/toasty
- Toffee malt
- Burnt sugar

These are many of the same qualities that you'd be looking for in a stout used for cooking.

Finally, [this discussion thread](https://www.homebrewtalk.com/threads/can-you-brew-it-recipe-for-wychwood-hobgoblin.273932/) from a homebrewing forum describes efforts to replicate it by hobbyists, and the comments there suggest that the original beer is not terribly bitter (~20 IBUs).  This is good news, as particularly bitter beer is the primary thing you'd want to avoid when using it as a dessert ingredient.

It won't be perfect, as an English strong ale probably won't be as sweet or as thick as a proper stout, but I doubt it'll be different enough to cause problems for your pudding.